# Android Service - Three different song is playing for one image

Tags: android

Hi I am creating a application for kids, It shows a Alphabets(Images) from A to Z in GridView. If u click S it will open the S in separate activity where you can swipe S to T,V,U...etc.. or You can swipe back to R,Q,P... etc.. And it has to play the song for S if u open S(For eg, S for Something). I achieved this using ViewPager.

What my problem is if I click S its playing the song for all R,S,T instead of playing a single track.

I don't know How to Fix it???

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    /**
     * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
     * */
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IndividualAlphabet.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MediaPlayerService.class));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MediaPlayerService.class));
}
}
```

Service (This is for Song)

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service{

MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myMediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.alphabets);
    myMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    myMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myMediaPlayer.stop();
}

}
```

For Individual Activity

```
public class IndividualAlphabet extends Activity {

private String[] alphabets;

public static int[] mRaw = {
    R.raw.a,R.raw.b,R.raw.c,R.raw.d,R.raw.e,R.raw.f,R.raw.g,R.raw.h,R.raw.i,R.raw.j,
    R.raw.k,R.raw.l,R.raw.m,R.raw.n,R.raw.o,R.raw.p,R.raw.q,R.raw.r,R.raw.s,R.raw.t,
    R.raw.u,R.raw.v,R.raw.w,R.raw.x,R.raw.y,R.raw.z
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_individual_alphabet);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    SwipeImageAdapter adapter = new SwipeImageAdapter(this);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.individual_alphabet, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void playSong() {

    startService(new Intent(IndividualAlphabet.this,MediaPlayerService.class));

}

public void stopSong() {

    stopService(new Intent(IndividualAlphabet.this,MediaPlayerService.class));

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    stopSong();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    stopService(new Intent(IndividualAlphabet.this,MediaPlayerService.class));
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();

    stopService(new Intent(IndividualAlphabet.this,MediaPlayerService.class));
}
}
```

And for Swipe Adapter

```
public class SwipeImageAdapter  extends PagerAdapter{


Activity activity;
Context context;
public static int[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
    R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
    R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f,
    R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
    R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j,
    R.drawable.k, R.drawable.l,
    R.drawable.m, R.drawable.n,
    R.drawable.o,R.drawable.p,
    R.drawable.q,R.drawable.r,
    R.drawable.s,R.drawable.t,
    R.drawable.u,R.drawable.v,
    R.drawable.w,R.drawable.x,
    R.drawable.y,R.drawable.z

};
public static int[] mRaw = {
    R.raw.a,R.raw.b,
    R.raw.c,R.raw.d,
    R.raw.e,R.raw.f,
    R.raw.g,R.raw.h,
    R.raw.i,R.raw.j,
    R.raw.k,R.raw.l,
    R.raw.m,R.raw.n,
    R.raw.o,R.raw.p,
    R.raw.q,R.raw.r,
    R.raw.s,R.raw.t,
    R.raw.u,R.raw.v,
    R.raw.w,R.raw.x,
    R.raw.y,R.raw.z
};

public SwipeImageAdapter(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
    this.context=act.getBaseContext();
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    view.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    view.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    MediaPlayer mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(activity.getBaseContext(),mRaw[position]);
    mp5.start();

    return view;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Someone help me to fix this app...

Comment: You are always passing `R.raw.alphabets` to `MediaPlayer.create` in the `MediaPlayerService`. Is that what you really want ?

Comment: R.raw.alphabets is a background song which start playing while the application starts. I individually added a song for all the alphabet for eg R.raw.a, R.raw.b, etc... This songs only playing for three times...